# Compressing InputStream using apache commons compress library

Tags: java, apache-commons-compress

I have a school assignment that requires my to take in an inputstream and compress it into a byte array with one of 5 formats (by the user specification) using the apache commons compress library. The 5 formats are: ZIP, JAR, SEVENZ, BZIP2 and GZIP. I wrote the following method to compress the input stream with the JAR format but am getting an illegalStateException with the string "No current entry".

```
private byte[] documentJARCompression(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JarArchiveOutputStream jarOut = new JarArchiveOutputStream(out);
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[out.size()];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = buffIn.read(buffer))) {
        jarOut.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    jarOut.close();
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Jar == Zip are multi-file compressions, where every file is an entry with filename.

Comment: Did you take a look at the [tutorial](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the javadocs for the Apache classes that you are using ... and its superclasses.   For example, the [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/ArchiveOutputStream.html) for `ArchiveOutputStream` (a supertype for the jar and zip archiver classes) says this:

> The normal sequence of calls when working with `ArchiveOutputStreams`
>   is:
>
> ```
> Create ArchiveOutputStream object,
> optionally write SFX header (Zip only),
> repeat as needed:
>     putArchiveEntry(ArchiveEntry) (writes entry header),
>     OutputStream.write(byte[]) (writes entry data, as often as needed),
>     closeArchiveEntry() (closes entry), 
> finish() (ends the addition of entries),
> optionally write additional data, provided format supports it,
> OutputStream.close().
> ```

You have launched straight into a `write` call without giving the archiver the information it needs about the entry you are adding to the JAR file.   That is what the `IllegalStateException("No current entry")` exception is saying.

You could also read the [examples](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html) in the documentation.  This explain (for example) that the archiver for 7z has a different superclass.

Note that zip, jar and 7z files are not simply compression formats.  They are archive formats for packing multiple files into a single archive.

---

In short, you should read an API's documentation before you try to use it.